# RNG in VB.Net 2010

Tags: vb.net, random, vb.net-2010

I'm making a simple dice rolling type game for my introduction to programming class and I need a bit of help with my random number generators. Every time I use them they follow they same sequence of numbers making each roll a tie, is there a way to fix this?

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim rnumber1 As Random
        Dim rnumber2 As Random
        Dim number1 As Integer
        Dim number2 As Integer
        Dim user1 As String
        Dim user2 As String
        Dim score1 As Integer
        Dim score2 As Integer
        rnumber1 = New Random
        number1 = rnumber1.Next(1, 6)
        rnumber2 = New Random
        number2 = rnumber2.Next(1, 6)
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my dice game!")
        Console.WriteLine("The objective of the game is to roll higher than your opponent.")
        Console.WriteLine("The first one to 10 points wins!")
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("First player, please enter your name.")
        user1 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you, {0}!", user1)
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("Second player, please enter you name.")
        user2 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you, {0}!", user2)
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
        Do Until score1 Or score2 = 10
            rnumber1 = New Random
            number1 = rnumber1.Next(1, 6)
            rnumber2 = New Random
            number2 = rnumber2.Next(1, 6)
            Console.Clear()
            Console.WriteLine("The score so far is {0} to {1}!", score1, score2)
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...")
            Console.Clear()
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, press enter to roll the dice!", user1)
            Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine(number1)
            Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, press enter to roll the dice!", user2)
            Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine(number2)
            Console.ReadLine()
            If number1 > number2 Then
                Console.WriteLine("The winner of this round is {0}.", user1)
                Console.ReadLine()
                score1 = score1 + 1
                Console.Clear()
            ElseIf number2 > number1 Then
                Console.WriteLine("The winner of this round is {0}.", user2)
                Console.ReadLine()
                score2 = score2 + 1
                Console.Clear()
            Else : Console.WriteLine("This round was a tie!")
                Console.ReadLine()
            End If
        Loop

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Visual Studio is not a programming language; it's an IDE. As your question isn't about use of Visual Studio, I've removed that tag and added the correct ones for VB.Net. If you're going to learn to program, you should at least learn to identify the language you're going to be using first. :-)

Comment: Create and use only one instance of `Random`, not two: replace `rnumber2` with `rnumber1`, and don't call `New Random` more than once.

Comment: Sorry Ken, I've only been doing this for about a week so it's all still pretty new and confusing to me!

Michael, which rnumber2 should be replaced with rnumber1 or did you mean replace all instances with it?

Comment: Get rid of `rnumber2` and use `rnumber1` exclusively. And delete the `rnumber1 = New Random` line inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved Your Problem.

Here is the Code, try it :

```
Sub Main()
    Dim rnumber1 As Random
    Dim rnumber2 As Random
    Dim number1 As Integer
    Dim number2 As Integer
    Dim user1 As String
    Dim user2 As String
    Dim score1 As Integer
    Dim score2 As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my dice game!")
    Console.WriteLine("The objective of the game is to roll higher than your opponent.")
    Console.WriteLine("The first one to 10 points wins!")
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Clear()
    Console.WriteLine("First player, please enter your name.")
    user1 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you, {0}!", user1)
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Clear()
    Console.WriteLine("Second player, please enter your name.")
    user2 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you, {0}!", user2)
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Clear()
    Do Until score1 Or score2 = 10
        rnumber1 = New Random
        number1 = rnumber1.Next(1, 6)
        rnumber2 = New Random
        number2 = rnumber2.Next(1, 6)
        rnumber2 = rnumber1
        number2 = rnumber2.Next(1, 6)
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("The score so far is {0} to {1}!", score1, score2)
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...")
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, press enter to roll the dice!", user1)
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine(number1)
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, press enter to roll the dice!", user2)
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine(number2)
        Console.ReadLine()
        If number1 > number2 Then
            Console.WriteLine("The winner of this round is {0}.", user1)
            Console.ReadLine()
            score1 = score1 + 1
            Console.Clear()
        ElseIf number2 > number1 Then
            Console.WriteLine("The winner of this round is {0}.", user2)
            Console.ReadLine()
            score2 = score2 + 1
            Console.Clear()
        Else : Console.WriteLine("This round was a tie!")
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Hope This Code Was Helpful To You.

Answer (score 0):

You must place a random at compile time:

```
Module Module1

    Dim rnumber1 As New Random
    Dim rnumber2 As New Random

    Sub Main()

        Dim number1 As Integer
        Dim number2 As Integer
        Dim user1 As String
        Dim user2 As String
        Dim score1 As Integer
        Dim score2 As Integer
        number1 = rnumber1.Next(1, 6)
        number2 = rnumber2.Next(1, 6)
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my dice game!")
        Console.WriteLine("The objective of the game is to roll higher than your opponent.")
        Console.WriteLine("The first one to 10 points wins!")
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("First player, please enter your name.")
        user1 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you, {0}!", user1)
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("Second player, please enter you name.")
        user2 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you, {0}!", user2)
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
        Do Until score1 Or score2 = 10
            rnumber1 = New Random
            number1 = rnumber1.Next(1, 6)
            rnumber2 = New Random
            number2 = rnumber2.Next(1, 6)
            Console.Clear()
            Console.WriteLine("The score so far is {0} to {1}!", score1, score2)
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...")
            Console.Clear()
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, press enter to roll the dice!", user1)
            Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine(number1)
            Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, press enter to roll the dice!", user2)
            Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine(number2)
            Console.ReadLine()
            If number1 > number2 Then
                Console.WriteLine("The winner of this round is {0}.", user1)
                Console.ReadLine()
                score1 = score1 + 1
                Console.Clear()
            ElseIf number2 > number1 Then
                Console.WriteLine("The winner of this round is {0}.", user2)
                Console.ReadLine()
                score2 = score2 + 1
                Console.Clear()
            Else : Console.WriteLine("This round was a tie!")
                Console.ReadLine()
            End If
        Loop

    End Sub

End Module
```

I hope it's work. It is because Random use a time in himself.